# How to load a defines file in Silex?

Tags: php, loading, silex

I'm new to silex, and I've got a file that creates a few defines. This is its content:

```
<?php 

namespace Config;

define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); 
define('ROOT',realpath(__DIR__ . '/../..')); 
define('CONFIG',ROOT.DS.'app'.DS.'config');
```

I'm trying to load it using my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.33",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.2",
        "boxedcode/silex-knp-menu-service-provider": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^3.2",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.2",
        "symfony/config": "^3.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Models\\": "src/MyApp/Models/",
            "Config\\": "src/MyApp/Config/"
        }
    }
}
```

The defines file is inside `src/MyApp/Config/`, so I therefore hoped this line would be enough to load the defines file in my index.php file:

> use Config\Defines;

But... it seems not... Can anyone tell me how to load the defines file so that I can use my Config class again?

Comment: Did you run `composer update` after changing the `composer.json`? Did you include `autoload.php` in `index.php` before trying to use any of the classes?

Comment: yes I've done both, and they work, since I can use classes like User.php

Comment: The PSR-4 autoload, loads classes, you are loading a file. Take a look at [how composer handles the autoloading of files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files). I've never used this feature but I think that adding the directive in your ```composer.json``` is enough, you don't have to add the ```use``` statement (which, AFAIK only loads classes also, not files). Otherwise you can just use the old ```require``` PHP function.